# the word "model" is not recognized in a razor view

Tags: razor, intellisense

The code I wrote: (file Index.cshtml)

```
    @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using WebApiSimple.ViewModels
@model ValuesViewModel
```

but the word model is not recognized. I started from a WebApi template and now I want to convert to a MVC. The webapi works but as I mentioned I cannot write razor views because the intellisense does not recognize the word "model"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The project was missing the web.config file in the View folder. I added that from another mvc project and now it works.